# Strange pending edit on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ssas-tabular

When I open a model.bim file in Visual Studio and then I close it without making any changes I see this:
[image]

Why do I see a pending edit on the .layout and the .smproj? how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that .smproj is updated because .layout is updated.

.layout could be updated if you changed anything in the measure grid or the diagram view. If the file didn't exist before, I believe it gets created automatically.

See [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140503075615/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2011/12/03/new-for-rc0-the-layout-file.aspx) for more information on the .layout file.

> We save out a lot of view state information for tabular models. Some
> of this view state information is something that you would want to
> share with other developers in a shared development environment. The
> position of measures in the measure grid and the position of tables
> and connectors in the diagram are two such examples.